# related to site and visualforcepages

Tags: visualforce, salesforce-id, site.com, website-integration

Hi is it possible to get images from go daddy  to visual force pages.if it possible can you explain clearly how the process is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First establish that you have permission to use the images. And referencing the images only makes sense if you know the images are not going to be removed i.e. you are co-ordinating your work with whoever is managing the go daddy site.

Go to the go daddy page that contains the image you are interested in e.g.:

```
http://foreveryoungcupcakes.com/
```

Put the cursor over the image (e.g. the square image in the body of the page) and right click to display an "Inspect Element" (called that in Chrome) window. Copy the "src" of the image e.g.:

```
images/6d16c91e375a03c553143e88d8ce25a5.jpg
```

and prefix it with the site to make the fully qualified URL e.g.:

```
http://foreveryoungcupcakes.com/images/6d16c91e375a03c553143e88d8ce25a5.jpg
```

and paste that into the browser URL to check it is correct.

Add the image in Visualforce using:

```
<apex:image url="http://foreveryoungcupcakes.com/images/6d16c91e375a03c553143e88d8ce25a5.jpg"/>
```

Repeat the above process for each image.

Comment: Mr Keith i am expecting like we use static resources in vf pages like is there any ways use from godaddy

Comment: @mahesh You can copy the images into static resources. Is that the process you are looking for? (Again you need to check that you have permission to do that.)

Comment: \what you have said the src url ,it is also similar we can get the images  from the website itself.what i want is "i dont want to store images in static resources i will store in godaddy and how can i use them in visual force pages without src url "

Comment: @mahesh To reference them from go daddy you will need to use fully qualified urls; these can be hard-coded in the Visualforce or made properties in a controller or controller extension. Don't really understand the "visual force pages without src url" comment.